# How to add a counting system to randomiser?

Tags: jquery, html, random

I have a randomiser, and I want to add a counting system that shows how many times a certain result came out.

For example: if I enter Hello and Goodbye, it has to count the times Hello came out, same for Goodbye. If possible, users have to select the max. score they want. For example: 3/5, 5/7 etc...

Can you also put a reset button in the code to reset the code and the scores? Here's my code for the randomiser:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
  <form>
  <hr/>
    <a href="javascript:;void(0);" id="buttonOne">Insert input form</a>
  <hr/>

    <input type="submit" value="Post the form" /> 

  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sequence = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#buttonOne").click(function(){
            $("form").prepend("<input name=name"+sequence+" placeholder='something' type='text' /> <br/> ");
            sequence++;
        });

        $("form").submit(function(e){

            $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
               if($(this).val() == "") $(this).remove();
            });

            if( $('input[type=text]').size() >= 2  ){

              random_number = parseInt( Math.random() * $('input[type=text]').size() );

                alert(  $('input[type=text]:eq('+random_number+')').val()  );

             }else{
              alert("sorry you need at least 2 fields");

             }
              return false;
        });

    });

  </script>
```

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this situation:

**1:** Create a 2D array. First value should be the word, second should be the amount.
**2:** When submitted, go through the array, if word is there, increment the number by one.
**3:** If word not found, add new value, and set the amount to 1.

Doing this, you can reset the variable by pressing a reset button. Simply by doing `array = [[]];` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I don't know much about arrays, so I think that would be pretty hard... Can you do it with vars or something too? Thank you for replying!

Comment: Arrays are really simple. I won't do this for you, as you have to learn it yourself. Look into arrays and you will see they're really simple.

Comment: Okay, I've followed a quick tutorial on arrays, and know what they are and when to use them, but how can I use this with this situation? Because this is in jQuery and Arrays are JS. If it is possible to use them, how do I have to use them (so they follow my wishes)? Also, how do I put the input from a user in an array)? Can you give me a short example? Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is also Javascript. It's just a library you include. When you do your submit, just change the array to the way you like. You already have the randomly selected text.